# How to boot into Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from dual boot when not able to select from grub

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have been working for a long time to get different versions of Linux to work, Ie Ubuntu and Mint. Since this is on my laptop, I have to use a partition. I booted into the Ubuntu installer via a CD, and installed it into the partition. However, when I restart the computer, it boots into windows and I cannot select the Ubuntu OS. This is really frustrating because I am not willing to delete windows and want to be able to dual boot. I need to know how I can boot into Ubuntu when I cannot access the grub boot menu like everyone else can.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from the Ubuntu installer in its "try before installing" mode and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Unfortunately, most likely a mistake by me, the Windows installation had gotten corrupted somewhere that made it impossible to download updates or anything of that sort. It had also been deactivated for some reason. So, I wrote Ubuntu over Windows 10 reluctantly. Thank you for your help anyway, and hopefully it may help someone else who may end up having the same problem. Sorry to waste your time.